# Create a register page with django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem, when I load my page and click on the register link, it gives out error 404. At this point I am frustrated, I have tried fixing them but to no avail

my index.html that shows the login page

```
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header-text"><a href="{% url 'login' % }">Login</a></div>
        <div class="header-text"><a href="{% url 'register' % }">Register</a></div>
    </header>
```

my register.html

```
{% extends 'index.html'}

{% block content}
<h2>Register</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    <p>
      {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
      {{ field }}
      {% if field.help_text %}
        <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
      {% endif %}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from.models import Post


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'register.html'
```

and my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import index, SignUpView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('register/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

Is there something i am missing?

Comment: What IS it showing?

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in Lasu_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1.admin/
[2.name='index']
3. register/ [name='register']
The current path, {% url 'register/' % }, didn’t match any of these.